# Catch anything and save it into a variable

Tags: python, except

I'm wondering if there is a keyword for "all" in python `except`.  I've ran into this seemingly simple problem:

```
try:
    #do stuff
except any as error:
    print('error: {err}'.format(err=error))
```

I know that you can do `except:` to catch all errors, but I don't know how to add an `as` keyword to get a `print`able object.  I want to catch any error and be able to get an object for use in printing or something else.

Comment: You can do a naked `except:`, but that considered a poor practice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can catch almost anything this way:

```
try:
    #do stuff
except Exception as error:
    print('error: {err}'.format(err=error))
```

But to catch really everything, you can do this:

```
import sys

try:
    #do stuff
except:
    err_type, error, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print('error: {err}'.format(err=error))
```

Comment: Thanks, what kind of things will the second example catch, but not the first one?

Comment: @JackHughes `SystemExit`, `StopIteration`, etc; things that aren't really errors and you really don't want to catch (at least not without immediately re-raising).

Comment: @chepner Hmm ok

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just catch `Exception`:

`except Exception as ex:`